# PHP Json_encode changing spaces to plus symbols +

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a web app where I first store JSON data in a cookie, then save to the database every x seconds. It just opens a connection to the server, and the server reads the cookie. It doesn't actually send anything via POST or GET.

While I save to the cookie, my data is formatted fine. However, when I work with it in PHP then setcookie a new json_encoded array, it replaces spaces with + symbols, and then these show up in my web app. I can't find any way to disable encoding of strings for json_encode, nor a JS way of parsing those plus symbols out (using jQuery.parseJSON; stringify's parse didn't work either)... Does anyone have any idea :S?

Comment: Spaces can be represented as `+` in URL encoded text and cookies are URL encoded so someone isn't decoding things at the right time.

Comment: Cheers. Got me thinking about urldecode. For some reason this works: `json_encode(urldecode($array))`, and I do that when I re-set the cookie at the end. Decoding when PHP reads in the cookie did nothing. Leads me to think json_encode may do something to it?

Comment: Where does the `+` first show up? Do you see it on the client when you extract your JSON from the cookie? Does it first appear on the server (before you try to treat the data as JSON)?

Comment: urldecode didn't actually fix it :p haha.. lol. Ok so the + ONLY shows up once I've run `setcookie('order',json_encode($newCookie),time()+18000, '/');` ... I parse it using `$.parseJSON(cookiecontents);` If I save data to the cookie from javascript, its fine. If i reload the page and parse the cookie again to fill out the order form, there's no +s. But when I set the cookie via PHP and then parse it, it adds the pluses. Something to do with it being passed as a response header from the server??

Comment: Ok so it looks like JSON.stringify(objects) encodes spaces as %20, but then either setcookie or JSON encode, encodes them as pluses (in the response header), and $.parseJSON() nor JSON.parse() can convert + to spaces... There's no way of setting the encoding type when you set a cookie is there?

Comment: **NEVERMIND** - To prevent setcookie from converting spaces to + plus symbols, I just had to urlencode(json_encode($newCookie)) so it was already encoded as %20 instead of a space :).

Comment: I think I've figured out what sort of nonsense is going on (see below), you're dealing with historical baggage and kludges, no wonder things are confused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

> Note that the value portion of the cookie will automatically be urlencoded when you send the cookie, and when it is received, it is automatically decoded and assigned to a variable by the same name as the cookie name. If you don't want this, you can use `setrawcookie()` instead if you are using PHP 5.

But I think you still want the cookie URL encoded, you just want `%20` for spaces instead of `+`. However, [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php):

> [...] for historical reasons, spaces are encoded as plus (+) signs

You could try using [`rawurlencode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) to encode it yourself:

> Returns a string in which all non-alphanumeric characters except `-_.~` have been replaced with a percent (%) sign followed by two hex digits. This is the encoding described in RFC 3986 [...]

And then `setrawcookie` to set the cookie. Unfortunately, none of [`decodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI), [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Functions/decodeURIComponent), or even the deprecated [`unescape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.unescape) JavaScript functions will convert a `+` back to a space; so, you're probably stuck forcing everyone to make sense the hard way.

Comment: That's really weird that there's no javascript decoding that replaces pluses with spaces. Thanks for that info though, I looked at setcookie and searched for decoding but I must have had my blind eyes on because I didn't see that, haha. Either way, I did manage to fix it by urlencoding the json_encoded array BEFORE setting it as a cookie, such that all spaces were encoded to %20 by that function, instead of + by setcookie. Didn't know setrawcookie existed either, thanks!!

Comment: @Benno: Hey, whatever works. I didn't know about `setrawcookie` until a couple hours ago either :) PHP isn't my strongest language but the PHP documentation is pretty good overall.

Comment: Actually, I had issues with doing it that way haha. I changed to using setrawcookie and rawurlencode and now there are no issues. I didn't detect it before because I had unescape when the cookie was parse to a JSON object. I removed the unescape because it was causing some issues with other characters as well....