# Call to json_encode puts extraneous '+' in output buffer

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, json

Sometime recently my WordPress plugin started failing in my DEV environment (on two different boxes) on an AJAX call.  What I see is that when I call:

```
$t = json_encode(<some array>);
```

an extraneous `+` character is inserted into the output buffer.  I observed this by viewing the result of an `ob_get_content()` call.  `$t` shows the correct JSON results, and the contents of `<some array>` doesn't seem to matter.

I determined it's not a PHP issue in and of itself, as it only seems to occur within the context of WordPress.

I isolated it to the following function in my plugin:

```
function my_action_callback() {
    $a = array("a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple");
    echo json_encode($a);
    die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}
```

`my_action_callback` is a callback function registered to be called by WordPress on an AJAX call. I can assign the results of `json_encode` to a variable instead of echoing, and the results are fine, but checking the output buffer at that point shows a single `+` already inserted.

Unfortunately, I am not sure what change I made in my environment started this behavior, since I waited too long to debug this.  I'm not sure where to start now.

The environment is PHP 5.3.5 running Wordpress 3.2.1

Why would calling `json_encode` put ANYTHING in the output buffer, since I am not echoing  the results?

Comment: Have a look at all your files. I guess there is a "+" somewhere between ob_start and your ob_get_contents..

Comment: Are you able to create some compact version of the code that will reproduce this problem?

Comment: Possibly related to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811845/php-json-encode-changing-spaces-to-plus-symbols

Comment: @halfdan, that was my first thought, but I checked the output buffer immediately before the call to json_encode() and its empty. Thej immediately after and there is a single '+'

Comment: @Jonathan, I had seen that post, but it really doesn't seem to apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a clean PHP env, write  and see if it prints the +. If it does, it's a PHP bug.

Get rid of the code above, put in your code and see if it prints the +. If it does, it's a bug in your code.

Start re-doing you modifications to the PHP env. Test, after each change, it it prints the +. When it does, you've found the culprit.

If, at the end, you still can't see the +, then it's magic. ;-)

Take home lesson: never let bugs linger around for too long.

Comment: I finally tripped over the errant '+' in a php file, just before the opening bracket.